# Do any URL Shortening services with link tracking have a https accessible url?

Tags: bit.ly, tinyurl

I have three websites that I want to generate tiny urls for search result pages every time someone clicks search. I like the http://bit.ly api and the fact that it offers tracking. However, it requires me to provide a password and does not offer ssl support. Does anyone know of a similar service that offers tracking, and a https accessible API?

Comment: Writing one is the easy part. Architecting the hardware setup when people start to use it is the hard part.

Comment: Scaling a url shortening service (there's no processing overhead...lookup URL by key, track visit, redirect) would not be your main scaling concern. I'm hoping the rest of your app would be far more difficult to scale.

Comment: My app is actually quite simple. http://lmsotfy.com. I'm also more concerned about edge cases, url tracking, etc etc. However, maybe I should write my own shortening service

Answer (score -1):

I think short URLs for HTTPs connections are really bad idea. After all SSL is here to ensure (part of its job) that you are actually talking to the server requested.

But in short URL scenario you are talking to a different server first - an ideal scammer situation.

Comment: I don't want to create https:// urls, I want to use a https:// url to make shortened urls.

Answer (score -1):

Bit.ly doesn't require you to send a password using their API; they require you to pass a token (aka API Key) that isn't in any way tied to your password.  It's an URL shortening service after all.  Considering all the information is pretty much public anyway, security shouldn't be a concern.